# Image-List (Collection of Images) with link to article

Tags: component

i want to create a page on which i want to list images. When you click on an image i want to open the full article with detailed information.

how can i achieve this in a simple way? which menuitem or module i should use?

Thanks for any help!

I use joomla version 3.3.6 and the afterburner2 template with gantry framework.

oodoloo

Answer (score 1):

What I use is [RokSprocket](http://demo.rockettheme.com/joomla-extensions/roksprocket/).

They have prebuilt layouts for various displays of images with descriptions/titles/links and it's fully responsive. There are a bunch of options for those without any CSS knowledge, but then if you do have some CSS skill you can do unlimited custom layouts.

Works to Joomla core articles and also Zoo.

Comment: Yeah, i tried RokSprocket before to implement a slider and i found it very nice. I tried to use it for my needs and i think its a good variant. The only thing i want is to disable the preview when i hover over an image ("read more" appears). i used the grid layout and assign an image for each item i added to the module.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any third-party extension for this, just use a category blog layout and an override to wrap the link around the article intro-image, exactly as described in your other question:

[Category Blog - open article on intro image click](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/category-blog-open-article-on-intro-image-click)

I've been doing exactly this in the template I built this week. The image below shows a category blog view, images link directly to the article and show article title and details on hover. No extensions just native Joomla functionality. Responsive image gird positioning and hover effects done entirely with css.

[image]

Comment: Ok, i tried the variant with category blog and i also found a solution to wrap the link around the article intro-image. But i think i will also try the solution with RokSprocket because there you can only show the images without a text beneath. I think with category blog i always have an image ont he left and a text on the right.

Comment: That's probably because you have the image float parameter still set to the Joomla default 'left'. Set it to 'none' in the options and the image will no longer float left.

Comment: Probably I expressed it wrong. The Problem is not the image - i don't want the Text beneath the image. I only want to have images and at the most a preview of the article if you hover over. But the hover effect is not necessarily.

Comment: Still possible, just don't place any introtext in your article. That will give you a list of images in your category blog view, and you can create a hover effect very simply with css. I've done exactly that in the template I've been building this week.

Comment: Wow, cool, that's exactly what i want! Can you give me a complete example or just an example for the hover with css? Thats enough, because the image-link to article i already solved in the other Question...

Comment: Can you give me some more information how you solved it ('Responsive image grid positioning and hover effects done entirely with css')?.

Comment: Better than that, I can sell you a copy of this template :) There's currently 50% off until the end of today, discount applied at checkout http://joomlanauts.com/joomla-templates/fotofit

Comment: Thanks :) - but then I try it myself until I figure out how I can achieve my purpose. I want to try and learn how to do something like that, not to buy a completed solution.

Comment: Then you already have the answers; create layout overrides to modify the core markup and then apply the styles you want in your template css.